# Access all files in different folders using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have four folders, is it possible to access them and get all the files?
[image]

I already tried this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/Precario/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/test/Negocio/Precario/Precario%20Documentos/Cap%C3%ADtulo%201%20-%20Pre%C3%A7%C3%A1rio%20CEMG')/Files",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

But only retrieve the "Secretariado Seccao de Empresa" file.

I could access each folder individually but it's not the idea, will it be possible to access them all at once?

Answer (score 1):

Requesting the Items collection for the library will bring back all items and folders regardless of what folder they are in. You can use the FileSystemObjectType or ContentType property to determine if the item is or is not a folder. In the example below I'm using the FileSystemObjectType.

```
function getItemsOrFolders(fileSystemObjectType) {
    var message = jQuery("#message");
    message.text("Working on it...");

    var url = appUrl + "/_api//Web/Lists/getByTitle('FolderTest')/Items?" + 
        "$select=*,FileDirRef"

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var fileOrFolderText = "files";
        if (fileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder) {
            fileOrFolderText = "folders";
        }
        message.text("All " + fileOrFolderText + ":");
        message.append("<br/>");
        jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
            if (item["FileSystemObjectType"] == fileSystemObjectType) {
                message.append(String.format(
                    "Title: {0};  Number: {1};  Id: {2}; Path: {3}",
                    item["Title"], item["Number"], item["Id"], item["FileDirRef"]));
                message.append("<br/>");
            }
        });
    });
    call.fail(failHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/test/Negocio/Precario/Precario%20Documentos/Cap%C3%ADtulo%201%20-%20Pre%C3%A7%C3%A1rio%20CEMG')/Files",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,file){
                console.log(file.Name);
            })
        },

        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```